# How do I reference my integer value in main without using setnumbers method

Tags: java, integer, output, return-type

Hello I am new to coding and making a program to calculate a speeding ticket fine but having trouble with setting up my integer variables without using setnums and printing them in my main so I can use my method to calculate tickets by inputting the speed and then the method calculating the total fine based on the speed limit,schoolzone, and mph over.

//main method

```
    public class TicketRunner 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    
      
      
      // add code for input here

      // Instantiate and print  
     
     Ticket test = new Ticket():
    
      
      System.out.print("\n Enter the Drivers Name?--> ");
      String name = keyboard.next();
      
      System.out.print("\n Drivers license Number?--> ");
      String tdl = keyboard.nextLine();
      
      System.out.print("\n Address?--> ");
      String addr = keyboard.nextLine();
      
      System.out.print("\n City?-->");
      String cty = keyboard.nextLine();
      
      System.out.print("\n State?--> ");
      String state = keyboard.nextLine();
      
      System.out.print("\n Zip?--> ");
      String zip = keyboard.nextLine();
      
      System.out.print("\n Did the violation occur in a school zone?  {Y/N} --> ");
      String School = keyboard.nextLine();
       
      System.out.print("\n Date of Violation:");
     
      System.out.print("\n Month Number?-->");
      int month = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.print(" Day?-->");
      int day = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.print(" Year?-->");
      int year = keyboard.nextInt();
      
      System.out.print(" \n What is the posted speed limit-->");
      int limit = keyboard.nextInt();
      
      System.out.print("\n How fast was the car driving travelling in mph?-->");
      int travel = keyboard.nextInt();
      
     
      System.out.println(" is  :: " + ticket.calcTicket(ticket));
      
    
      
      
  
   }
}


//method

    public class Ticket
{
   //Driver Information
   private String name, TDL, address, city, state, zip;

   //Violation Information
   private int postedSpeed, travelling, ticketAmount, day, month, year;
   private boolean schoolZone;

   public Ticket()
   {
   name = "";
   TDL = "";
   address ="";
   city = "";
   state ="";
   zip = "";
   
   postedSpeed=0;
   travelling=0;
   ticketamount=0;
   day=0;
   month=0;
   year=0;

   }

   public Ticket(String nm, String tdl, String addr, String cty, String st, String zp, int pSpd, int travel, int d, int m, int yr, String school)
   {
   name = nm; TDL = tdl; address = addr;  city=cty; state=st;  zip=zp; postedspeed=pSpd; travelling=travel; 
   
   
   day=d; month=m; year=yr; schoolZone=school;
   
   
   }
   
   public void calcTicket()
   {
   
   
   if (travel>postedSpeed)
   {
         over=travel-postedSpeed;
  
   }
   else
   {
         over=0;
    
    }
    
     //base fine and fine for every mph past the limit
     
         if  (over<0)
   

   {
  
       base=0;
   
   }
  
   else if (over>0)
   {
   
       base=75;
   
       base=over*6;
   
   
   }
   //fine for being 30mph over speed limit
   else if (over>30)
   {
   
   
         ticket = base+160;
   
   }
   
   //school zone fine
   
   if (over<0)
   
   {
       zone=0;
      
   }
    
    else if (school.equals("Y"))
    
   {
   
          zone= base*2;
     
     }
     
     else if (school.equals("N"))
     
          zone = base*1;
     
     }
    
     
   
   public String lastName()
   {
      return "";
   }
   
   public String toString()
   {
      
      //returning method to main
      
      return "";  + base + zone; 
      
     
  
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please add more details about `setnums` and elaborate on the actual problem?

Comment: In your main(), you should use the detailed version of the Ticket constructor. In ``calcTicket()`` you use a ``if (over < 0)``, which can't happen. You should either use <= 0 or just == 0.

Comment: Also, it's a `void` method. It won't return anything, so you won't see any result.

Comment: Your code is rather hard to read (very, very understandable for a beginner, please do not be put off!!!).  First: ideally, you would present your code in two code blocks with a white gap separating them: one for the TicketRunner class and one for the Ticket class.  Second: have a read through https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf, starting at section 4.  It's an old document, but easy to read, and making your code easier to read will help you and everyone else who looks at your code (whether to advise you, use your code or update it).  Welcome to programming :)

Comment: Issues spotted in TicketRunner: 1) the line declaring a new Ticket ends in a colon rather than a semi colon (are you using an IDE, e.g. IntelliJ?  That would flag up such typos immediately for you).  2) you don't use this Ticket, called 'test', but you do use an undeclared variable called 'ticket'; are these supposed to be the same item?  3) when you call method calcTicket() you pass it a variable, but the only method I can see called calcTicket() does not take any parameters so this will not compile.  Hint: the method belongs to the 'ticket' object, which already knows about itself.

Comment: Also in TicketRunner: your final line of executable code will not work, as you are attempting to build a String from a String plus a method with a void return type.  You need to change calcTicket() to ```return``` a String of the value that you want to add to the line to be printed.  (I believe this is the issue @Spectric is referring to.)

Comment: When you declare a Ticket within the TicketRunner class, you are using the zero-parameter constructor.  When you then go on to ask the user to provide the required values, you are assigning them to newly declared variables which have nothing to do with those in the Ticket object even though they share the same name.  (I have a computer, you have computer, I am pretty sure they are not the same computer.)  You need to do, e.g. ```ticket.name = keyboard.next();```, which will require either public variables or loads of setters in the Ticket class.  Or move the data collection into Ticket :)

Comment: You seem to have a whole load of variables in Ticket which have not been declared, so they will not compile.  Seriously, get IntelliJ if you don't yet have it.  There's a free version, and it is *incredibly* helpful at pointing this stuff out for you as you go.  I am learning a lot from it myself, and it really does make programming a much smoother experience.

Comment: PLEASE do not be put off by that wall of comments!  You look like you want to do cool stuff with Java, which is great :)  Take your time, work through the suggestions, and you will end up with some code which will be much easier to work with.  This won't solve your underlying problem, but it will make it a lot easier to find and solve.  DO DO DO keep coming back here for help, there are loads of great folk around who know masses and will happily assist you if they can see you are trying your best to figure things out and learn.